# Which deflate (zip) algorithm characteristics can cause a 50% compression factor on the recompression of certain data?

Tags: zip, compression, deflate, lossless-compression

It's well-known that recompression (compressing a compressed dataset) generally yields a very low (or no) compression.

Hence, I've been very surprised to find a dataset where the second ZIP recompression yields a roughly 50% compressions factor (tested via two runs of the Unix `zip` tool, on maximum compression factor (`9`)).

Therefore, I'm curious: which characteristics (limits) of the Deflate algorithm, can cause such behavior? I've tried other programs, and for example, algorithms like zstd yield a much better compression on the first pass.

For reference, the dataset is [here](https://github.com/wheremyfoodat/Gameboy-logs/raw/master/Blargg10LYStubbed1.zip).

Answer (score 3):

Deflate is limited to a match length of 258 bytes. If there are often repeated strings much longer than that, then a second compression may yield fruit. zstd codes match lengths up to 128K bytes.

gzip -9 once on your data gives 36340381 bytes. gzip -9 twice on your data gives 18860632 bytes. zstd -9 once gives 18985681 bytes. A second zstd -9 reduces it only slightly to 18882745 bytes.

Comment: If I use Info-Zip's LZ77 for Deflate (with the length limit 258 and distance limit ~32KiB) and encode further with a simple implementation of the "MA" part of LZMA, I get 20464328 bytes Zip file. Perhaps the 258 bytes match length limit doesn't explain everything for this data.

Comment: The 258 bytes constraint explains the limited first compression. How that compressed data is then compressed again is an entirely different matter, as the resulting repetitive patterns are at the level of bits in the stream.

Comment: Actually the remarkable aspect of that example is that the repetitive compressed chunks of the first compression are 8-bit aligned and can be compressed further significantly.

Comment: Each repetition does not have to be 8-bit aligned, because eight copies of a non-8-bit aligned repetition _will_ be 8-bit aligned. E.g. if each repetition is 7 bits, eight of those will be seven bytes. With enough of them, those seven _bytes_ will repeat, and then it can be compressed.